# How to iterating through an array of list and accessing items in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops

This list below has multiple ASK, BID, LAST price. How do I get the last ASK and BID price while iterating over this list using python?

```
aList = 
[
 ({'BID'}, 0.36), 
 ({'ASK'}, 0.37), 
 ({'LAST'}, 0.36), 
 ({'BID'}, 0.35), 
 ({'ASK'}, 0.36), 
 ({'BID'}, 0.34), 
 ({'ASK'}, 0.35), 
 ({'LAST'}, 0.34)
]
```

```
Desired output:
ASK = 0.35
BID = 0.34
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dictionary to always hold the last seen value:

```
dict = {}
for item in aList:
     dict[list(item[0])[0]] = item[1]
```

and your dict will be:

```
{'BID': 0.34, 'ASK': 0.35, 'LAST': 0.34}
```

You can then print your desired (`BID` and `ASK`) values.

---

Another approach would be using `index()` function and reversing the list:

```
keys = [list(item[0])[0] for item in aList]
last_ask_index = keys[::-1].index("ASK")
last_bid_index = keys[::-1].index("BID")
print(f"ASK: {aList[::-1][last_ask_index][1]}, BID:{aList[::-1][last_bid_index][1]}")
```

and the output is:

```
ASK: 0.35, BID: 0.34
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one of the options :

```
out = {n.pop(): p for (n, p) in aList if "ASK" in n or "BID" in n}

#1.65 µs ± 79.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
```

Or, as suggested by @[*Kelly Bundy*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12671057/kelly-bundy), here is another variant :

```
out = {n: p for [n], p in aList if n in ["ASK", "BID"]}

#1.98 µs ± 74.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
```

Output :

```
print(f"ASK = {out['ASK']}\nBID = {out['BID']}")

ASK = 0.35
BID = 0.34
```

Comment: `for [n], p in aList`

Comment: How did you benchmark? Quite possibly incorrectly.

Comment: I mean, try the benchmarking without the `if "ASK" in n or "BID" in n`. Does it still work, or does it crash (because the first of the million loops pops the data and then the other 999999 work on the already emptied sets)?

Comment: I benchmarked with a classical `%%timeit`. Feel free to correct every detail you judge inaccurate, I’m AFK!